# selected="selected" not populate inside drop down in <option> tag

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome, html-select

I have a dropdown , I will show the drop down to two kind of categories  **Admin** and **User**

I need to populate If the dropdown contains empty values automatically populated in the Screen .My problem is  Its working fine in the One (Admin)category  , the (User) category its not working . Below I pasted the code I got in my chrome console `ELEMENTS` tag .

Working

```
<select ng-model="dept" ng-change="deptCh(dept,buildNameng)" ng-options="option.floor as option.floor for option in dptData 
| unique:'floor'" style="width: 12%;" ng-if="floorNotNull" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope">

<option value="" class="" selected="selected">---Floor---</option><option value="string:" selected="selected"></option></select>
```

Not Working

```
<select ng-model="dept" ng-change="deptCh(dept,buildNameng)" ng-options="option.floor as option.floor for option in dptData 
| unique:'floor'" style="width: 12%;" ng-if="floorNotNull" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched">
<option value="" class="" selected="selected">---Floor---</option><option value="string:"></option></select>
```

I got the code like above in chrome console . The working code has selected="selected" inside the **END** of option tag when I logged as **ADMIN**.

```
<option value="" class="" selected="selected">---Floor---</option><option value="string:" selected="selected"></option></select>
```

The not working code doesnt have this selected="selected" inside the **END**option tag when I logged as **USER**.

```
<option value="" class="" selected="selected">---Floor---</option><option value="string:"></option></select>
```

If I manually added `selected="selected"` this in chrome `edit as html` inside the not working `option` tag its working fine .

I dont know why this code working in one type but not working another type also the selected="selected" not coming if I login as the "USER" type. I will post my whole drop down code below

```
<div ng-show="(staticData == 2) ? trueVar : (firstTimeSubject == 9) ? trueVar : falseVar">
          <label ng-if="floorNull" for="singleSelect">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  Floor: </label>
          <select ng-if="floorNull" ng-model="dept" ng-options="option.id as option.floor for option in dptData | unique:'floor'" style="width:12%" ng-change="deptCh(dept,buildNameng)">
            <!-- You can have ONE default, null selection option.-->
            <option value="">---Floor---</option>
          </select>
          <label ng-if="floorNotNull" for="singleSelect">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  Floor: </label>
          <select ng-if="floorNotNull" ng-model="dept" ng-options="option.floor as option.floor for option in dptData | unique:'floor'" style="width:12%" ng-change="deptCh(dept,buildNameng)">
            <!-- You can have ONE default, null selection option.-->
            <option value="">---Floor---</option>
</div>
```

Snap of chrome

Working Snap in chrome console
[image]

Not Working snap in chrome console
[image]

The above not working snap I marked as **RED CIRCLE** code is not populate automatically inside the `option` tag `selected="selected"` in the **USER** category login. The `selected="selected"` is automatically chrome added I didnt add any thing in my code .

Please guide me  I am not getting any error I am tested this is in Google chrome.

Comment: We need more information to answer this question.
Are you using AngularJs 1, and can you show the deptCh function and the (relevant part of, or whole) angular module?

Comment: yes I am using angular 1

Comment: I did so many condition inside that method thats why I wouldnt post that method @twicejr

Comment: plz add "angularjs" tag to your question, it will be more likely to get good answers

Comment: As per my `ng-if` condition it shown correct drop down as per my condition but the action is not happened . I meant action is if the `dptData ` array has any empty value it will populated automatically empty in `ngmodel` place this part is working fine in ADMIN logged in . But Not working while the USER logged in

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto ok I wil add bro

Comment: Create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) to reproduce this..

Comment: @developer033 please have a look at my code If may not understand before   , Now I added the snap of the problem , the chrome added automatically in my code inside option tag selected="selected"

Comment: The Not working snap I marked **Red circle** its not added I dont know why If I am manually added at the end using chrome console its populated the EMPTY VALUE on the drop down .@developer033

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-selected` directive to specify when your item should be selected.

You can also assign to a controller function that return a boolean to allow you to do more action.

Comment: Please have look at my snap , I didnt add any `selected` in my code . Chrome automatically added . The  Not working snap see its not added I dont know why If I am manually added its working.

Comment: yes in fact browser automatically add a selected attribute to the default option of your select tag. it s often the first option tag. like you are in angular you should not use the selected attribute. the proper way to master this attribute is To use the ng-selected directive. like that you will be a le To choose which element you want To be selected and mastered the browser behavior.